# Store Map<Enum, Enum> as String

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, enums, jpa-2.0

I need help with storing a map in JPA2, where both keys and values are enums (`Map<Enum, Enum>`). With Hibernate as my JPA provider it stores the enums as a blob but I need the data stored as strings. I tried the following annotations to fix this problem:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@MapKeyEnumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
public Map<Enum, Enum> getElementsMap() {
    return elementsMap;
}
```

But the data is still being stored into the DB as blob. Has anyone solved this problem?

Comment: Saving a map as a string doesn't sound sensible at all. Have you heard of data normalization?

Comment: Sorry, I write this question in wrong manner, now it's fixed, I mean keys and it's values.

Comment: You can just use `toString()` on both the keys and values. What's the problem?

Comment: I don't thik so that this is the very basic stuff, look at this post:
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=999270&start=0
Maybe you should consult a Java beginners book.

Comment: @Niklas B. Before you write something and someone recommended that he should read something, think twice! If you really don't understand a problem and don't know the specific solution, please don't spam questions with your irrelevant comments and try to study somethink before you post your answer.

Comment: I don't agree. If you know how to put a string into your DB and if you know how to convert an instance of an `enum` into a string (which you were told you could `toString()` for), you have all the required knowledge to put this into practice. Both are very basic things, IMHO. Putting the ideas together is also a very basic thing. What's the specific problem, then? **EDIT:** Your comment to Mikko's answer shows that your actual problem is a very different one. You talk about strings, but your DB accepts BLOBs.

Comment: By the way, the reason why I suggested a simple tutorial is because you answered "I don't know how to do this" to the suggestion to use `toString()`. This has nothing to do with Hibernate whatsoever.

Comment: At firts every "beginner" knows that, enum use name() method to convert its instances (it's best practice). The second I don't have any error messages (you should read my question carefully again). If you have that skills like you presents, than put this very basic things together and write a correct answer (it would be very simple thing for you) otherwise don't waste my and your time with your irrelevant answers!

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question. The first thing you'd have to explain is why you want to use a BLOB to hold a string. The second thing is to specify the binary format that you want to use to store and retrieve the string to and from the data base. By the way, "commenting" is not the same as "answering". We all waste our time here reading your underspecified question, so why aren't we allowed to "waste" a bit of your time to make it possible to help you?

Comment: "I don't know how to do this" this answer was meaning in hibernate, not how to use toString().

Comment: You should have made that clear, then.

Comment: Ok, let me little correct you, its not "answer" but "comment" (you click on "Add Comment" button)! So here the missing information just for you: I use hibernate to generate DDL schema for me and its generate table whth bytea type to store enum. So here is the point. I don't want to use BLOB to hold an enum. I want from hibernate to generate DDL with VARCHAR type for this enum. Is this information enought for you? Because seams like @Mikko Maunu understand this very well.

Answer (score 3):

@Enumerated is used to to define type for value. Following maps to table where column for both key and value are varchars and name of the enum will be saved:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@MapKeyEnumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
public Map<MyEnum, MyOtherEnum> elementsMap = new HashMap<>();
```

It will produce roughly following table:

```
[NAME_OF_ENTITY]_ELEMENTSMAP (
  NAME_OF_ENTITY_ID INTEGER, 
  ELEMENTSMAP VARCHAR(255), 
  ELEMENTSMAP_KEY VARCHAR(255)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, I tried it, but didn't help me. I use postgresql db and hibernate create int8, bytea, bytea data types in table.

Answer (score 1):

Almost each and every Java Object has a `toString() method` If you want to represent your Map in the database, then I suggest this be your option.

However I have to ask are you sure it is the MAP you wish to store and not the elements of the keys or values?

Comment: Yes, it's the keys and it's values, Sorry I'm starting with JPA2 and hibernate, can you post the here the changes in code which must I do to store this keys and values as String?